# Error when displaying database table data to listview on VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using vb.net 2013 and database sql server express. When i try to displaying database to listview, i get error like this

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Additional information: Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Add' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Function Add(item As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem) As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem':
        Argument matching parameter 'item' cannot convert from 'DBNull' to 'ListViewSubItem'.
    'Public Function Add(text As String) As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem':
        Argument matching parameter 'text' cannot convert from 'DBNull' to 'String'.*

And my code like this :

```
Sub ListViewForMasterBiaya()
    Call DatabaseConnection()
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    CMD = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM EntriBiaya", CONN)
    DA = New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
    DS.Clear()
    DA.Fill(DS, "EntriBiaya")
    DT = DS.Tables(0)
    ListViewMasterBiaya.Items.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListViewMasterBiaya
            .Items.Add(DT.Rows(i)("NoKode"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("JenisBiaya"))
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("NoPol"))
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("Debit"))
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("Kredit"))
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("Tabungan"))
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("Angsuran"))
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("Klaim"))
                .Add(DT.Rows(i)("TotalDiterima"))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

And the error shows in line 19. Is something wrong? Please help

Comment: The very first thing you should do is turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties. You should also turn it `On` in the IDE options so that it is `On` by default for future projects.  You'll then find that your code won't compile because you are not passing to that `Add` method what it requires.  If it's your intention to pass a `String` then you must state that explicitly by casting or converting the `Object` reference you get from your `DataRow` to type `String`.

Comment: You probably ought not to be using a `ListView` at all.  I see a lot of beginners use them when they should be using a grid control.  You already have a `DataTable` so you probably ought to simply assign that to the `DataSource` property of a `DataGridView`.  That will automatically create the columns and the rows and each cell will contain the actual data from the table, rather than a `String` representation of it.  If you need any sort of customisation then the `DataGridView` can handle that too. Only use a `ListView` if you need multiple views or groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific issue is that, while some of your fields do contain a `String` and the abovementioned cast/conversion can be done implicitly, at least one field is NULL and thus contains `DBNull.Value`, which is not a `String` or any other type that that `Add` method is expecting, which is what the error message is telling you. If you expect to pass a `String` to `Add` when the field is NULL then you need to create one.

The easiest option is to simply call `ToString` on the `Object` reference you get from the `DataRow`.  That will handle data that is already a `String`, other types of data and NULLs too, because `DBNull.ToString()` returns `String.Empty`, e.g.

```
.Add(DT.Rows(i)("TotalDiterima").ToString())
```